# What is xarray.DataArray.expand_dims supposed to do?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am trying to add a new dimension with some length to a DataArray.

I have tried using the expand_dims method, whose documentation indicates that I should be able to do this

http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.expand_dims.html#xarray.DataArray.expand_dims

"Dimensions to include on the new variable. If provided as str or sequence of str, then dimensions are inserted with length 1. If provided as a dict, then the keys are the new dimensions and the values are either integers (**giving the length of the new dimensions**) or sequence/ndarray (giving the coordinates of the new dimensions)."

I tried this but with no luck.

```
test = xr.DataArray([1,2,3,4,5,6])

test
Out[114]: 
<xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 6)>
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
Dimensions without coordinates: dim_0

test.expand_dims({'dim_1':3})
Out[115]: 
<xarray.DataArray (dim_1: 1, dim_0: 6)>
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
Dimensions without coordinates: dim_1, dim_0
```

I see that the additional dimension in the array is there from the extra brackets, but the length is one:

```
test.expand_dims({'dim_1':3}).shape
Out[120]: (1, 6)
```

I suppose I was expecting the shape to be either (3,6), expanding the data, or (3,2), reshaping it.

What am I doing wrong or not understanding? I just discovered xarray so it is entirely possible this is a conceptual thing I am not getting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
test.expand_dims(dim_1 = 3)
Out: 
<xarray.DataArray (dim_1: 3, dim_0: 6)>
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
Dimensions without coordinates: dim_1, dim_0

test.expand_dims(dim_1 = 3).shape
Out: (3, 6)
```

I refered to this: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2710

Comment: This is helpful, but it would be even better to also know how to do the reshaping to `(3, 2)` that @jammertheprogrammer referred to in their question.

Comment: Adding an extra dimension would always duplicate the array in the other dimension. If you want to reshape it, then you can just do that first and then add another dimension. xarray won't automatically reshape it